# Where can I find samples of MS-DOS/Win9x Viruses to record/test?

Tags: virus, ms-dos, windows-98, windows-95

Since MS-DOS and Win9x are basically oldies now, I think it's safe to ask this question.

Where can I, as a YouTuber, find MS-DOS and/or Windows 95/98 viruses on the internet? I would like to record the payload and upload the videos to YouTube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://vxheaven.org/ - "This site contains a massive, continuously updated collection of magazines, virus samples, virus sources, polymorphic engines, virus generators, virus writing tutorials, articles, books, news archives etc. Even the viruses for the platforms you've never heard of. We also offer free hosting for virus authors and groups.".

They've got most of the ancient MSDOS viruses [virii?], and most of the Win 9x ones as well. Pretty much everything there is so outdated that every AV should have signatures in their db against them, so I don't see any problem with posting this link today. Also the website is setup in a way that it's very difficult to accidentally infect yourself, as any binaries are zipped up and in a very obvious section to avoid confusion.